# MaterialUI show and hide the Container's gutters based on breakpoints

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I want to disable the gutters for `xs`, `sm` and `md`. And to enable them at `xl` and beyond.

However this doesn't work.

```
    <Container maxWidth={"xl"} disableGutters={{ xs: true, xl: false }}>
```

Am I doing something wrong–because the API mentions that a boolean can be passed to `disableGutters`?

Comment: You can write a custom hook that returns the correct props based on current breakpoint. More detail in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69898963/9449426) answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mr.Polywhirl said *disableGutters* accepts only boolen value
you can solve it as following:

```js
function Layout({children}) {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const lessThanXL = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("xl"));

  return <Container maxWidth="xl" disableGutters={lessThanXL}>{children}</Container>
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `disableGutters` prop only accepts a boolean, so you are using the API wrong.

> ### [Container API - Props](https://mui.com/api/container/#props)
>
> | Name | Type | Default | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | `disableGutters` | `bool` | `false` | If `true`, the left and right padding is removed. |

So your code must look something like this

```
<Container maxWidth={"xl"} disableGutters={false}>
```

Comment: Right. So what I am trying to achieve is `show` the gutters at `xl` and beyond and `hide` them at breakpoints smaller than `xl`. This doesn't do that...

Comment: I am not sure if the API can handle that requirement. I think you should leverage the sx prop and the breakpoints provided through the theme object to remove the padding and accomplish your goal